# Why mapped pairs get obliterated?

Tags: scala, scalding

I'm trying to understand the example [here](https://github.com/twitter/scalding/blob/master/tutorial/MatrixTutorial5.scala) which computes Jaccard similarity between pairs of vectors in a matrix.

```
val aBinary = adjacencyMatrix.binarizeAs[Double]

// intersectMat holds the size of the intersection of row(a)_i n row (b)_j
val intersectMat = aBinary * aBinary.transpose
val aSumVct = aBinary.sumColVectors
val bSumVct = aBinary.sumRowVectors

//Using zip to repeat the row and column vectors values on the right hand
//for all non-zeroes on the left hand matrix
val xMat = intersectMat.zip(aSumVct).mapValues( pair => pair._2 )
val yMat = intersectMat.zip(bSumVct).mapValues( pair => pair._2 )
```

Why does the last comment mention non-zero values? As far as I'm aware, the `._2` function selects the second element of a pair independent of the first element. At what point are `(0, x)` pairs obliterated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, I don't know anything about scalding but this seems odd. If you look at `zip` implementation it [mentions specifically](https://github.com/twitter/scalding/blob/0.8.5/scalding-core/src/main/scala/com/twitter/scalding/mathematics/Matrix.scala#L583) that it does an *outer join* to preserve zeros on either side. So it does not seem that the comment applies to how zeroes are actually treated in `matrix.zip`.

Besides looking at the dimension returned by zip, it really seems this line just replicates the `aSumVct` column vector for each column:

```
val xMat = intersectMat.zip(aSumVct).mapValues( pair => pair._2 )
```

Also I find the `val bSumVct = aBinary.sumRowVectors` suspicious, because it sums the matrix along the wrong dimension. It feels like something like this would be better:

```
val bSumVct = aBinary.tranpose.sumRowVectors
```

Which would conceptually be the same as `aSumVct.transpose`, so that at the end of the day, in the cell (i, j) of `xMat + yMat` we find the sum of elements of `row(i)` *plus* the sum of elements of `row(j)`, then we subtract `intersectMat` to adjust for the double counting.

**Edit:** a little bit of googling unearthed this blog post: http://www.flavianv.me/post-15.htm. It seems the comments were related to that version where the vectors to compare are in two separate matrices that don't necessarily have the same size.